# C# async HttpWebRequest deadlocking

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, httpwebrequest

For few hours I am struggling with async code in C# and I can't really get why is my code deadlocked. 
So far I've red many articles and anything ringed the bell for me.

Hope you can help me.

Here is the code I am trying to run.

Main

```
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        Task<EventDetailed[]> events = getDetailedEvents();
        await events;
    }).Wait();
```

getDetailedEvents:

```
 static async Task<EventDetailed[]> getDetailedEvents()
        {
            ...
            EventDetailed[] result = await LoadDetailedEventsDetailsAsync(evnts).ConfigureAwait(false);

            return result;
        }
```

And the core of my problem.

LoadDetailedEventsDetailsAsync

```
async static Task<EventDetailed[]> LoadDetailedEventsDetailsAsync(Event[] events)
        {
            List<EventDetailed> detailed = new List<EventDetailed>();
            List<Task<WebResponse>> responses = new List<Task<WebResponse>>();
            List<Event> tasksWithStream = new List<Event>();
            foreach (Event e in events)
            {
                var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://...");
                ... some headers etc ... 
                e.Stream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStreamAsync();
                e.WebRequest = httpWebRequest;
                tasksWithStream.Add(e);
            }
            foreach (var tsk in tasksWithStream)
            { 

                try {
                    await tsk.Stream.ConfigureAwait(false);
                    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(tsk.Stream.Result))
                    {
                        streamWriter.Write("...");
                        streamWriter.Flush();
                        streamWriter.Close();
                    }
                    responses.Add(tsk.WebRequest.GetResponseAsync());
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Logger.mes("Failed to get event data.");
                }
            }
            foreach (var response in responses)
            {
                try
                {
                    await response.ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Logger.mes("Failed to get event data.");
                    continue;
                }
                parseData.Add(ParseData(response));
            }
```

Comment: What type of application is it? A Console Application? WPF? Windows Forms?

Comment: How does the `Event` class look like? Specifically, what is the definition of `Event.Stream`?

Comment: Don't `await` on `getDetailedEvents`. Since you're calling `Wait` on the state machine, it deadlocks.

Comment: @YacoubMassad: It is Console Application. And declaration is 
public Task<Stream> Stream { get; set; }

Comment: @FilipEkberg: Sounds great, I will try it out ASAP! Hope that then I will understand why this code deadlocks. Btw as a fix you suggest to remove await in first call and just use its result?

Comment: Also, you don't have to await LoadDetailedEventsDetailsAsync in getDetailedEvents. Just return the Task and let the caller await it.

Comment: @FilipEkberg, AFAIK `Wait` can cause a deadlock only if we are on a UI thread since continuations would need to run on the UI thread that is blocked by `Wait`. However, in this case there are no UI threads

Comment: @YacoubMassad There's a bit more to it than that, but yes, in a Console Application it wouldn't cause a deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

A couple points:

First, it's important to note that you should *almost* never call `.Wait` (or `.Result`) on an async task - you should use `await` instead. One of the *very* few exceptions is in the `Main` method of a console app. The reason is that if you don't block the main thread, your program will simply exit prematurely.

Second, if you need to make multiple HTTP requests that do not depend on each other (i.e. request B does not need the results of request A), then there are huge performance gains to be had by executing them in parallel. Better still, you are not consuming a thread per request because the calls are asynchronous, i.e. they don't block a thread while waiting for a response, so the same thread can effectively fire off many concurrent requests.

I won't re-write your code, but I will suggest how I'd restructure it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // start all async tasks in parallel.
    var tasks = GetEvents().Select(GetEventDetailsAsync);

    // wait for them all to complete. normally you should use await instead of Wait,
    // but you can't because you're in the main method of a console app.
    Task.WhenAll(task).Wait();
}

static IEnumerable<Event> GetEvents()
{
    // build a list of whatever metadata is needed to do your async work.
    // do NOT do any actual async work here.
}

async static Task<EventDetailed> GetEventDetailsAsync(Event e)
{
    // do all async work here, use await as needed,
    // but only for one event (no loops).
}
```